# Why doesn't camerax sample project put constant inside a class?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is from [camerax sample](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/PermissionsFragment.kt) project.

`PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE` is a constant, I think it would be put inside a class, just like Code B.

I think Code B can reduce the couple and more clear

Is the Code A better Code B?

**Code A**

```
private const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 10
private val PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

class PermissionsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (!hasPermissions(requireContext())) {
            // Request camera-related permissions
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            // If permissions have already been granted, proceed
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                    PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults.firstOrNull()) {
                // Take the user to the success fragment when permission is granted
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission request granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                        PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission request denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

   ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
private val PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)

class PermissionsFragment : Fragment() {

    private val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 10

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (!hasPermissions(requireContext())) {
            // Request camera-related permissions
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            // If permissions have already been granted, proceed
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                    PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults.firstOrNull()) {
                // Take the user to the success fragment when permission is granted
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission request granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                        PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission request denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE` is a `const val`, i.e. a compile-time constant. You can only put `const val`s at the top level (as in this example), or in an `object` (e.g. the `companion object`).

Comment: Thanks! I can use the code `private val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 10` and put it inside `class PermissionsFragment`.

Answer (score 3):

By adding request code as [`compile-time constant`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants), it can be accessed without keeping an instance of the class(like `static` modifier in Java).

> Properties the value of which is known at compile time can be marked as compile time constants using the const modifier. Such properties need to fulfil the following requirements:
>
> Top-level, or member of an object declaration or a companion object.
>   Initialized with a value of type String or a primitive type
>   No custom getter
>   Such properties can be used in annotations

The code sample makes a fragment with sole responsibility of handling Camera permission. While `onActivityResult()` is handled inside fragment, there might be a scenario later on when you want to do some work *in Parent Activity* based on the result, like for example removing this fragment when the request is complete. In order to do that, you would need access to this request code in Activity. By adding request code as [`compile-time constant`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants), it can be accessed without keeping an instance of the fragment.

Other than that, there is no merit/demerit in either approaches since you will only making one instance of this fragment throughout your app anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to put the constant inside a companion object. This will allow you to make the PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE constant AND statically accessible without the need to have an instant of PermissionsFragment.

Like this:

```
class PermissionsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (!hasPermissions(requireContext())) {
            // Request camera-related permissions
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            // If permissions have already been granted, proceed
            Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                    PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == grantResults.firstOrNull()) {
                // Take the user to the success fragment when permission is granted
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission request granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container).navigate(
                        PermissionsFragmentDirections.actionPermissionsToCamera())
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permission request denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 10
    }

}
```

Outside of PermissionsFragment you would be able to access it by writing `PermissionsFragment.PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE` if you remove the private visibility modifier.